# How I can get svg file name after webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

How I can get name after webpack transform in vue 3?

[image: Red - before, Black - after]

I try to create dynamic path in computed method

```
  let iconPath = computed(() => {
    return `~@/assets/icons/${props.iconName}.svg#${props.iconName}`;
  });
```

Comment: What do you mean? The generated `hash`?

Comment: Yes, yes, sure, hash

Comment: Why do you want to get that in the first place?

Comment: I wanna generate dynamic path to SVG Icons. This path generating in computed method and returns path

Comment: @kissu i added computed method code

Comment: Sorry if I'm a bit slow on this one, but why would you need something else here? Isn't the part until to `[...].svg` enough here?

Comment: @kissu because I using <use> tag and id is required :(

Comment: At the end, a package like `nanoid` could generate a UUID in the same way. No need to get attached to this particular hash IMO.